# "call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of" error when tried to pass argument to a method

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm, trying to use CPTL thread-pool for my application.

So, i have a function with this definition:

```
static void Invoke( int id, std::unique_ptr<BaseService> svc );
```

And tried to pass it to CPTL "push" method to be queued in thread-pool:

```
pThreadPool->push( std::ref(App::Invoke), std::move( svc ) );
```

But I received this error:

```
/home/hadi/CLionProjects/App/App.cpp:211:27: error: no matching member function for call to 'push'
    pThreadPool->push( std::ref(App::Invoke), std::move( svc ) );
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/home/hadi/CLionProjects/App/include/cptl/ctpl.h:152:14: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with F = std::__1::reference_wrapper<void (int, std::__1::unique_ptr<BaseService, std::__1::default_delete<BaseService> >)>, Rest = <std::__1::unique_ptr<BaseService, std::__1::default_delete<BaseService> >>]: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr<BaseService, std::__1::default_delete<BaseService> >'
        auto push(F && f, Rest&&... rest) ->std::future<decltype(f(0, rest...))> {
             ^                                                        ~~~~
/home/hadi/CLionProjects/App/include/cptl/ctpl.h:171:14: note: candidate function template not viable: requires single argument 'f', but 2 arguments were provided
        auto push(F && f) ->std::future<decltype(f(0))> {
             ^
1 error generated.
```

Can anybody please tell me how to fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is non-copyable, you want to pass an rvalue reference `std::unique_ptr<BaseService>&&`

Comment: Is it safe to change the my function definition to : `static void Invoke( int id, std::unique_ptr<BaseService> & svc );` and pass the svc object to it `std::move( svc )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems CPTL either has a bug at the [line 152](https://github.com/vit-vit/CTPL/blob/master/ctpl.h#L152) or doesn't support move-only arguments (can't find any documentation on it so can't be sure):

```
    auto push(F && f, Rest&&... rest) ->std::future<decltype(f(0, rest...))> {
```

Even though `push` uses `std::forward<Rest>(rest)...` in the invocation, it uses `rest...` in the SFINAE, which fails and excludes the overload from the list of viable candidates.

Normally the arguments of packaged tasks are stored in a queue, and thus are required to be copyable. That precludes the use of `unique_ptr` since it's not copyable (it's unique!).

As a workaround you can use a `shared_ptr` or, if the lifetime of `svc` exceeds the lifetime of the thread pool, a raw pointer.

Comment: I agree with the diagnose, but I doubt that storing something in a queue would mandate that it be copyable.

Comment: @rustyx, Thanks for the reply. Just wanted to make sure if Is it safe to change the my function definition to : static void Invoke( int id, std::unique_ptr<BaseService> & svc ); and pass the svc object to it std::move( svc )

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good design. Passing a unique_ptr by reference defeats the purpose of lifetime management of the unique_ptr.